# Sendmail and gnupg

Tags: wordpress, gnupg

I am looking for a way to configure wordpress on my RHEL4 machine to send out email notifications using gnupg (sendmail).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress uses it's own function `wp_mail()` to send out emails. Since it is a 'pluggable' function, you can override it with your own version in a [WordPress plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin);

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: GNUPG Mail
 * Description: Send mail using GNUPG.
 */

function wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers = '', $attachments = array())
{
    // use the PHP GnuPG library here to send mail.
}
```